# Wordpress vs php or asp.net

Tags: json, wordpress, web-services, parsing

Is it possible to use a wordpress website similarly as php or asp.net websites to access jason webservice? If It is possible is there any limitations? Which is better to use knowing that I need to use it to send and receive json objects to and from the db server, and will need it to display events, news, items, buying and booking. Note that I am using the same webservice on a mobile application. Thankyou in advance

Comment: Wordpress is php, you'll need to code a plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is it possible to use a WordPress website similarly as PHP or ASP.net websites to access JSON webservice?**

Yes. WordPress is built with PHP, and PHP provides the necessary tools you need to access a JSON webservice, and convert these into PHP Objects.

**Are there any limitations?**

No.

**Which is better to use? (WordPress vs ASP.net)**

WordPress is a content management system, where as ASP.net is a framework. WordPress will, without modifications, be efficient at managing content such as events, news and items. ASP.net will not provide these things for you out of the box.